# How to do ordering Using Lambda in C# when ordering is based on multiple condition

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have one query in sql and I want to convert that query in C# lambda.

below is my Query.

```
 select 1col,2col, 3col, 4col,5col, 6col, 7col, 8col from XYZ
    order by xcol, (
        CASE zcol WHEN 'XYZ' THEN 1 ELSE (
        CASE zcol WHEN 'aaa' THEN 2 ELSE (
        CASE zcol WHEN 'www' THEN 3 ELSE (
        CASE zcol WHEN 'ttt' THEN 4 ELSE (
        CASE zcol WHEN 'rtt' THEN 5 ELSE (
        CASE zcol WHEN 'drd' THEN 7 ELSE 6 
        END) END) END) END) END) END), IssueDate
```

I am try to convert this query to C# linq lambda syntax but don't understand that How applies multiple condition on order by.

first order of order by is fixed but second one is dynamic and 3rd one is again fix.

Comment: what do you mean by "second one is dynamic"? Can the strings used in the case statement change?

Comment: String is not changed but order of columns is based on that.

Comment: What are you having trouble with `OrderBy().ThenBy().ThenBy()` or composing the `switch` in the `ThenBy()`

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Answer (score 3):

First, I believe you can lose the repeated CASE statements in your original query:

```
 select 1col,2col, 3col, 4col,5col, 6col, 7col, 8col from XYZ
    order by xcol, (
        CASE zcol
        WHEN 'XYZ' THEN 1
        WHEN 'aaa' THEN 2
        WHEN 'www' THEN 3
        WHEN 'ttt' THEN 4
        WHEN 'rtt' THEN 5
        WHEN 'drd' THEN 7
        ELSE 6
        END), IssueDate
```

For the "linq lambda syntax", you can use `.OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...).ThenBy(...)` with the apprioriate expressions in each. The second order by expression would become a `switch` expression in C#

```
context.XYZ
    .OrderBy(xyz => xyz.xcol)
    .ThenBy(xyz => xyz.zcol switch {
        "XYZ" => 1,
        "aaa" => 2,
        "www" => 3,
        "ttt" => 4,
        "rtt" => 5,
        "drd" => 7,
        _ => 6
        })
    .ThenBy(xyz => xyz.IssueDate)
    .Select(xyz => ...);
```

ADDENDUM: If the switch expression above is not usable for the object environment in use, the following equivalent using conditional (ternary) operators  might work.

```
context.XYZ
    .OrderBy(xyz => xyz.xcol)
    .ThenBy(xyz =>
        xyz.zcol == "XYZ" ? 1 :
        xyz.zcol == "aaa" ? 2 :
        xyz.zcol == "www" ? 3 :
        xyz.zcol == "ttt" ? 4 :
        xyz.zcol == "rtt" ? 5 :
        xyz.zcol == "drd" ? 7 :
        6)
    .ThenBy(xyz => xyz.IssueDate)
    .Select(xyz => ...);
```

Comment: I am confused here. ThenBy 1,2,3,4 is the column number ? still my issue is not solved because columns are with different datatype. so I getting error in then by.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "ThenBy 1,2,3,4". The switch expression should be equivalent to the CASE statement in your original post. The numbers are actual values (not column numbers) and effectively order the zcol based on the sequence "XYZ", "aaa", ..."rtt", anything else, and with "drd" last. As for the data types, the .OrderBy() and .ThenBy() can handle a variety of types.  Also, when you say you are getting an error, be specific. What error?

Comment: Before I can help further, I need for you to update your original post with your table definition, some sample data, and expected results. Adding this along with your original query to a db<>fiddle would be very useful.

Comment: Downvoted because its is not compilable and not suitable to EF or other ORM's. Use conditional operators instead of `switch`.

Comment: Based on @SvyatoslavDanyliv's constructive feedback, I added an alterative above that replaces the switch expression with a ternary conditional that may be more ORM friendly.